# How do you find the largest product of 4 consecutive numbers in a grid?

Tags: python-3.x, file

Here's the problem: 
Find the largest product of a horizontal or vertical line of four consecutive numbers in this grid. Here, "consecutive" means four numbers that lie next to each other in the same row or column. For example, the top row starts with the four consecutive numbers 8, 2, 22, and 97. Consecutive numbers do not "wrap around" sides of the grid.

I know that I should convert the grid into a number of lists and kind of go through each quad (pairs except 4 instead of 2). But I'm not sure how to save it as a file and how to do anything with this to code to the answer.

My SPECIFIC question is what exactly is the problem asking me to do and what would be the pseudocode? Taking 4 two-digit numbers and multiplying them does not give an 8-digit number (unless I'm crazy).

I have no code as of now.
Here is the 20x20 grid:

[image]

It should output an 8-digit number.

Comment: Please view the grid before providing help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(10)
a = np.random.randint(1,10,(6,7))
func = lambda arr,n:(arr[:,np.arange(arr.shape[1]-n+1)[:,None] + np.arange(n)]).prod(2).max()
np.r_[func(a,4),func(a.T,4)].max()
```

Now Using the GRID:

```
import io
grid = np.loadtxt(io.StringIO(GRID))
np.r_[func(grid,4),func(grid.T,4)].max()
Out: 51267216.0
```

Without using numpy, you could do:

```
from functools import reduce

prod = lambda lst: reduce(lambda x,y:x*y,lst)

def slice_grid_max(grid,n):
    n_cols = len(list(zip(*grid)))
    f = lambda grid: max([prod(j[i:i+n]) for j in grid for i in range(n_cols-n+1)])
    return max((f(grid),f(zip(*grid))))
slice_grid_max(grid,4)
Out: 51267216.0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to solve this problem using Python's standard library without having to resort to any third-party modules, you can use the following program as a demonstration of how you could go about doing that:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import enum

# The grid was converted here: https://easypdf.com/ocr-online
# After some manual cleanup of the conversion, you have this:
GRID = '''\
08 02 22 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08
49 49 99 40 17 81 18 57 60 87 17 40 98 43 69 48 04 56 62 00
81 49 31 73 55 79 14 29 93 71 40 67 53 88 30 03 49 13 36 65
52 70 95 23 04 60 11 42 69 24 68 56 01 32 56 71 37 02 36 91
22 31 16 71 51 67 63 89 41 92 36 54 22 40 40 28 66 33 13 80
24 47 32 60 99 03 45 02 44 75 33 53 78 36 84 20 35 17 12 50
32 98 81 28 64 23 67 10 26 38 40 67 59 54 70 66 18 38 64 70
67 26 20 68 02 62 12 20 93 63 94 39 63 08 40 91 66 49 94 21
24 55 58 05 66 73 99 26 97 17 78 78 96 83 14 88 34 89 63 72
21 36 23 09 75 00 76 44 20 45 35 14 00 61 33 97 34 31 33 95
78 17 53 28 22 75 31 67 15 94 03 80 04 62 16 14 09 53 56 92
16 39 05 42 96 35 31 47 55 58 88 24 00 17 54 24 36 29 85 57
86 56 00 48 35 71 89 07 05 44 44 37 44 60 21 58 51 54 17 58
19 80 81 68 05 94 47 69 28 73 92 13 86 52 17 77 04 89 55 40
04 52 08 83 97 35 99 16 07 97 57 32 16 26 26 79 33 27 98 66
88 36 68 87 57 62 20 72 03 46 33 67 46 55 12 32 63 93 33 69
04 42 16 73 38 25 39 11 24 94 72 18 08 46 29 32 40 62 76 36
20 69 36 41 72 30 23 88 34 62 99 69 82 67 59 83 74 04 36 16
20 73 35 29 78 31 90 01 74 31 49 71 48 86 81 16 23 57 05 34
01 70 54 71 83 51 54 69 16 92 33 48 61 43 52 01 89 19 67 48'''
CONSECUTIVE = 4


def main():
    matrix = convert_grid_to_matrix()
    products = {}
    calculate_horizontal_products(matrix, products)
    calculate_vertical_products(matrix, products)
    largest_products = calculate_largest_products(products)
    display_largest_products(matrix, largest_products)


def convert_grid_to_matrix():
    return tuple(tuple(map(int, line.split())) for line in GRID.splitlines())


def calculate_horizontal_products(matrix, products):
    calculate_all_products(matrix, products, Orientation.HORIZONTAL)


def calculate_all_products(matrix, products, orientation):
    for row, column in generate_starting_coordinates(matrix, orientation):
        products[(row, column, orientation)] = calculate_product(
            get_numbers(matrix, row, column, orientation)
        )


def calculate_product(numbers, start=1):
    for value in numbers:
        start *= value
    return start


def generate_starting_coordinates(matrix, orientation):
    if orientation is Orientation.HORIZONTAL:
        for row in range(len(matrix)):
            for column in range(len(matrix[row]) - CONSECUTIVE + 1):
                yield row, column
    elif orientation is Orientation.VERTICAL:
        for row in range(len(matrix) - CONSECUTIVE + 1):
            for column in range(len(matrix[row])):
                yield row, column
    else:
        raise ValueError(f'{orientation!r} is not a valid orientation')


def get_numbers(matrix, row, column, orientation):
    if orientation is Orientation.HORIZONTAL:
        return matrix[row][column:column + CONSECUTIVE]
    if orientation is Orientation.VERTICAL:
        return tuple(
            matrix[row + offset][column] for offset in range(CONSECUTIVE)
        )
    raise ValueError(f'{orientation!r} is not a valid orientation')


def calculate_vertical_products(matrix, products):
    calculate_all_products(matrix, products, Orientation.VERTICAL)


def calculate_largest_products(products):
    max_value = max(products.values())
    for key, value in products.items():
        if value == max_value:
            yield key


def display_largest_products(matrix, largest_products):
    print('The largest product(s) can be found here:')
    for coordinate in largest_products:
        print('    Row: {}, Column: {}, {}'.format(*coordinate))
        display_calculation(matrix, *coordinate)


def display_calculation(matrix, *coordinate):
    numbers = get_numbers(matrix, *coordinate)
    operation = ' * '.join(map(str, numbers))
    print(f'        {operation} = {calculate_product(numbers):,}')


@enum.unique
class Orientation(enum.Enum):
    HORIZONTAL = enum.auto()
    VERTICAL = enum.auto()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I am getting errors around line 70.

Comment: @rm13 The code should work with Python 3.6 or later.

Comment: i know that but it doesn't work

Comment: @rm13 Does it work all right if you try it here? https://repl.it/repls/FriendlyLividScience

Comment: Yes it does thanks